# incorrect position of \hat in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

The following code generates a simple plot, where the y axes has a label generated by a LaTeX command

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

plt.figure()
hatdelta = '$\hat{\Delta}$'
xlist = np.array([ 0, 1 ])
ylist = np.array([ 1, 2 ])
plt.errorbar(xlist, ylist, fmt='o', capsize=2)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylabel(hatdelta, fontsize=16)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

I am using jupyter-notebook to run the code.
This is the actual result:

[image: plot]

A close inspection of the y axes reveals that the LaTeX is incorrectly rendered:

[image]

The hat is not centered over the symbol. However, the LaTeX code should correctly center the hat. This is, for example, the output of a LaTeX source with the same command:

[image]

Is it possible to fix this incorrect LaTeX rendering?

Comment: Does it look the same if you use the same font?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't know how to choose the latex font in python.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# To use LaTeX
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

plt.figure()
hatdelta = '$\hat{\Delta}$'
xlist = np.array([ 0, 1 ])
ylist = np.array([ 1, 2 ])
plt.errorbar(xlist, ylist, fmt='o', capsize=2)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylabel(hatdelta, fontsize=16)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Or

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
# Improve \hat
hatdelta = '$\hat{\,\Delta}$'
xlist = np.array([ 0, 1 ])
ylist = np.array([ 1, 2 ])
plt.errorbar(xlist, ylist, fmt='o', capsize=2)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylabel(hatdelta, fontsize=16)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```